# Mailchimp API 3.0 does not send welcome emails

Tags: mailchimp

I am trying to subscribe user to mailchimp list, like this

```
 $MailChimp = new MailChimp($apikey);
 $result = $MailChimp->post('lists/'.$list.'/members', array(
                    'email_address'     => $email,
                    'status'            => 'subscribed',
                    'send_welcome'      => true,
                    'double_optin'      => false
));
```

Email was subscribed but no Welcome Email was sending to user. I turn on "Send a final welcome email" in mailchimp settings for this list. But it does not work. Please give me an advice

Comment: I had a conversation with the MC support about this very same issue a few months ago, and I was told, that when using a single opt in, there is no way to send Welcome Mails when subscribing via API. They suggested to use an "Automation Workflow" for sending the mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/) the request body parameter no longer accepting that parameter. It was there on API 2.0.